# Click event in leaflet plugin - How to make the click event to work only inside the map tile image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

I have 256*256 image. I have setup the image in leaflet as mentioned bellow.

```
var cloudmadeUrl = tileserver + '/' + selected_map + '/tiles_{z}_{y}x{x}.png';

cloudmade = new L.TileLayer(cloudmadeUrl, {maxZoom: 4, noWrap: true, continuousWorld: true });

map = new L.Map('map', {
          center : latlng, 
          zoom : 0, 
          layers : [cloudmade], 
          tms: true
       });
```

I have click event for the map. Now the click event will work if i click outside the tile image.

How to make the click event to work only inside the map tile image?

Comment: Need more information.  Can you show the click event code?  Can you put together a JSFiddle that replicates the problem?

Comment: @Josh here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shri1920/jPMfm/). I want to make the click event to display alert when i click only on tile. Now it is displaying alert when i click outside the map tile also.

Comment: @Josh [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shri1920/jPMfm/3/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of worrying about the map bounds (since it is tied to the container and not the tilelayer) you could worry about the click event target.  See [Match event.target with existing jquery object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8027847/match-event-target-with-existing-jquery-object) for a suggestion.

Here's a [working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xHBc5/).  It uses `event.originalEvent` in the Leaflet code to gather the information on the original click event.  Then it does something based on the class of the click event.

Comment: Thank you for the fiddle. It Works fine for leaflet plugin. But i am also using leaflet marker cluster on the leaflet plugin. So event.originalEvent.target will not give the target div. Do you have any idea how to handle this issue in leaflet marker cluster?