# On click of a dynamically created element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I added a div element into a variable and appended it to the document:

```
var faceDiv = $("<div class='dropDownJsFace dropDownJsArrowDown' />");
```

Now I'm attempting to reference that div within the `.on()` function via `e.target` like so

```
$(document).on("click", function(e){
    if(e.target == faceDiv)
    {
        alert("done");  
    }
});
```

To clarify, I want it to specifically reference that dynamically created div, as apposed to the class `.dropDownJsFace`.

Comment: `$(facediv).on("click"...`? `$(document).on("click", ".dropDownJsFace .dropDownJsArrowDown", function ...`?

Comment: That duplicate question doesn't answer my question.

Comment: if (e.target == faceDiv[0]) { ...

Comment: This is actually a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8027847/match-event-target-with-existing-jquery-object

Answer (score 0):

Just use the selector parameter to `.on`:

```
$(document).on("click", "div.dropDownJsFace", function(e) {
        alert("done");  
});
```